# Display number of attempts left for incorrect password, accept if user inputs correct Password

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I have begun my programming journey a week ago with zero previous knowledge of coding.
I also watched video on how to post stack overflow question, so would love constructive feedback.

> Details:
>
> Language - Python
>
> Version - 3.8.3
>
> Editor - VS Code

I am trying to write a program that takes input from user and checks if it is a valid password. If yes, it displays "Correct" and exits program, if incorrect, it shows number of attempts left, 3 in total, and asks for input again.

I just reached **WHILE** loop portion in my tutorial and used that to make the program.

```
msg = input("What's the secret password: ")

# Password attempt is 3 times, starts at 2, then 1 and ends when counter is 0
num = 2  

# bananas is the correct password
while msg != "bananas":  
    if num == 0:
        print("Too many wrong attempts. You are locked out!")  # exhausted all 3 attempts, should print given message.

    else:
        print(f"Wrong Password! You have {num} chances left")  # password incorrect, display attempts left
        msg = input("What's the secret password: ")
        num = num - 1

print("Correct")
```

**Problem**

If I run it and give correct password straightaway or after 1-2 failed attempts, it runs as expected.
But if I give wrong input all 3 times, it goes into the loop of displaying the message

> Too many wrong attempts. You are locked out!

And prints it forever. I am unable to figure out, where to exit the loop so that it only displays the message once and exits the program.

Kindly help with resolving the issue.

[2 incorrect password, 1 correct in 3rd attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6gb3.jpg)

[all 3 incorrect attempts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by2ed.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this structure:

```py
num = 3
while input("What's the secret password: ") != "bananas" and num-1 != 0:
    num -= 1
    print(f"Wrong Password! You have {num} chance" + ['_', ' ', 's '][num] + "left")
print("Correct") if num else print("Too many wrong attempts. You are locked out!")
```

The input can directly be used on the while condition - if you have zero attempts left or get the correct password the while loop breaks and `if num:` (num greater than zero - True) the appropriate message gets displayed.

And as a function:

```py
def pswd_entry(num=3):
    while input("What's the secret password: ") != "bananas" and num-1 != 0:
        num -= 1
        print(f"Wrong Password! You have {num} chance" + ['_', ' ', 's '][num] + 
    "left")
    print("Correct") if num else print("Too many wrong attempts. You are locked 
    out!")
```

Note: `pswd_entry(num=3)` has an optional argument `num` which will default to `3` if left blank.

---

### Explained

Our number of tries:

```py
num = 3
```

**The While Loop**

First condition:
`input("What's the secret password: ") != "bananas"`

`input()` will wait until the user enters a value and if this value is not "bananas" then the while loop will not break.

Second condition:
`num-1 != 0`

This will check that the number of tries (minus one) is not (`!=`) equal to 0.

If condition 1 `and` condition 2 are met the while loop will run.

One attempt is subtracted `num -=1` (the same as `num = num -1`) and then the warning for number of chances left is written.

The `+['_', ' ', 's '][num]` will select whether the `'s'` is added to chance/s -
for example if there is 1 chance left (i.e. `num = 1`) just `' '` (a space) is added to `'chance'`

If `num = 2`:

`['_', ' ', 's '][2]` - (`[0 element, 1 element, 2 element][select 2 element]`) = 's ' is added to `chance` -> `chances`

```py
while input("What's the secret password: ") != "bananas" and num-1 != 0:
    num -= 1
    print(f"Wrong Password! You have {num} chance" + ['_', ' ', 's '][num] + "left")
```

**Finally** - The print statement

```py
print("Correct") if num else print("Too many wrong attempts. You are locked out!")
```

The `if num` will do `print("Correct")` if the value of `num !=0` - the if check here checks that `num` has a value and is not zero (False) - otherwise it will print the lock out message (from `else`).

Comment: thanks leopard, i will go through this and try and understand the logic.

Comment: @obelisk No worries - Please don't hesitate to ask any specific questions - much appreciated

Comment: Please bear with me. I am happy that so many people have come forward to help and some have provided multiple methods. It is taking me time to run thru all of these and understand how it works.

Comment: Hi @leopardxpreload, I think there are a few issues with the code,  (1) I think it should be "num -= 1", which reduces value of num in each iteration; instead of "num = -1" which assigns new value of -1 to num.  (2) if i enter Correct password in 1st or 2nd attempt, it accepts and displays "Correct" but if I enter 2 wrong attempts and enter correctly in 3rd attempt, it still gives me "Too many wrong attempts. You are locked out!"

Comment: @obelisk Hi ! - I've done a bit more testing for you this time - hopefully this will work a bit better with the new edit !

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this.  But it looks a lot more scary and complicated now.

Comment: @obelisk Yes some odd unexpected characters can be daunting - Let me do an overview for you

Answer (score 1):

Here's code not to duplicate input statements

```
password, times = 'bananas', 3
while True:
    times -= 1
    msg = input("What's the secret password: ")
    if msg == password:
        print("Correct")
        break
    elif times > 0:
        print(f"Wrong Password! You have {times} chances left")
    else:
        print("Too many wrong attempts. You are locked out!")
        break
```

Function is good to separate your job ino small parts. you can find the difference between this one and above.

```
def login(password, times=3):
    while True:
        times -= 1
        msg = input("What's the secret password: ")
        if msg == password:
            print("Correct")
            return True
        elif times > 0:
            print(f"Wrong Password! You have {times} chances left")
        else:
            print("Too many wrong attempts. You are locked out!")
            return False

result = login('bananas')
if result:
    print('Login sucessful !')
else:
    print('Login failed !')
```

Comment: thanks Jason. I will try both methods. Try to understand how it works. And when I have learnt about functions, I will try to go thru this again.

Comment: For your first code: if i enter 3 wrong password, it gave an output of  - 

Wrong Password! You have 0 chances left
Too many wrong attempts. You are locked out!

I do not want the line  - Wrong Password! You have 0 chances left. So I updated the last ELSE statement. and want to revise your original answer. Hope it is ok. Let me know if you think it is an improvement.

Comment: Update statements as general steps for login.

Comment: HI. I did not understand your comment. Would you please clarify so i get a better idea. Also thanks for updating your code. I am running it to understand the logic

Comment: Just do it in three steps: 1. input password, exit with 'Correct' information. 2. If not and more chance to re-enter password, then show previous input is wrong and how many chances left. 3. If no more chance, show locked and exit.

Answer (score -1):

By putting this in a function you can use `return` after printing to exit the program.

```py
def main():
    msg = input("What's the secret password: ")

    # Password attempt is 3 times, starts at 2, then 1 and ends when counter is 0
    num = 2  

    # bananas is the correct password
    while msg != "bananas":  
        if num == 0:
            print("Too many wrong attempts. You are locked out!")  # exhausted all 3 attempts, should print given message.
            return
        else:
            print(f"Wrong Password! You have {num} chances left")  # password incorrect, display attempts left
            msg = input("What's the secret password: ")
            num = num - 1

    print("Correct")


main()
```

Comment: Thanks. I think it should be def main(): instead of def main()   ... my editor showed an error, so i guessed that would fix it. Also is there no way to do it without Functions, since I haven't reached that far yet.

Comment: @obelisk Yes you're right. You can do, but it wouldn't be as clean.

Comment: Can you help with that method? Thanks for your help with the function. Much appreciated

Comment: @obelisk No, as it's poor and leads to many problems down the road.